window.open('', 'test'); open a new "about:blank" window, instead of focus existing "test" window
I have a web application that open multiple external popup window eg.:
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow')

The end user, can open multiple window of my application and I want that only one window for target exists. The solution I have adopted is a BroadcastChannel for share beetween my application instances the information if a target window is already opened.
broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'open', value: 'stackoverflow'});
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow');

all application instances listen for the message and collect opened target windows
 const openWindowsTarget = [];
 broadcastChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
    if( event.data.type === 'open' ){
        openWindowsTarget.push(event.data.value);
    }
 }

In this way if a target window is opened somewhere, the window is opened without url, just with the target
 if (openWindowsTarget.includes('stackoverflow') ) {
    window.open('', 'stackoverflow');
 } 

the window in this way is just focused without reload.
This behavior works in the past, but in the present day the effect is a new "about:blank" window is opened. Probably something is changed in the browser side.
I'm finding a solution for fix then!
For test/help save this snippet into an html file (example.html), open into two separate window and click on the button
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="openWindow('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow')">
      Open stackoverflow
    </button>
    <script>
      const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('WindowService');
      const openWindowsTarget = [];

      broadcastChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data.type === 'open') {
          openWindowsTarget.push(event.data.value);
          console.log({openWindowsTarget})
        }
      };

      function openWindow(url, target) {
        if (openWindowsTarget.includes(target)) {
          window.open('', target);
        } else {
          broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'open', value: target });
          openWindowsTarget.push(target);
          window.open(url, target);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

I have also tried to change approach and send a broadcast message for focus the window, but the focus() has no effect, if the window is minimized, it remain minimized
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="openWindow('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow')">
      Open stackoverflow
    </button>
    <script>
      const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('WindowService');
      const openWindowsTarget = [];
      const localWindows = {};

      broadcastChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data.type === 'open') {
          openWindowsTarget.push(event.data.value);
          console.log({openWindowsTarget})
        }
        if (event.data.type === 'focus') {
            if( localWindows[event.data.value] ){
                localWindows[event.data.value].focus();
            }
        }
      };

      function openWindow(url, target) {
        if (openWindowsTarget.includes(target)) {
          broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'focus', value: target });
        } else {
          broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'open', value: target });
          openWindowsTarget.push(target);
          localWindows[target] = window.open(url, target);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Other ideas?

The documentation says: If an empty string ("") is specified or this parameter is omitted, a blank page is opened into the targeted browsing context. I don't think it has ever meant to leave the specified window unchanged if it already exists.

calling focus() through the broadcast channel won't work, the window that opened the popup needs to be active and it requires a user gesture.

Perhaps a solution that checks the existence of a window would be suitable. Although your original script did not cause any problems for me.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  
<script>
let windowObjectReference = null; // global variable
function openWindow(url, windowName) {
  if (windowObjectReference === null || windowObjectReference.closed) {
    windowObjectReference = window.open(url, windowName);
  } else {
    windowObjectReference.focus();
  }
}
</script>

  <body>
    <button onclick="openWindow('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow')">
      Open or create a window named `stackoverflow`
    </button> 
  </body>
  
</html>


This don't works on multiple application instances

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="openWindow('https://stackoverflow.com/', 'stackoverflow')">
      Open stackoverflow
    </button>
    <script>
      const broadcastChannel = new BroadcastChannel('WindowService');
      const openWindowsTarget = [];
      const localWindows = {};

      broadcastChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data.type === 'open') {
          openWindowsTarget.push(event.data.value);
          console.log({openWindowsTarget})
        }
        if (event.data.type === 'focus') {
            if( localWindows[event.data.value] ){
                localWindows[event.data.value].focus();
            }
        }
      };

      function openWindow(url, target) {
        if (openWindowsTarget.includes(target)) {
          broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'focus', value: target });
          console.log(target);
          localWindows[target].focus(); // <--------- this line
        } else {
          broadcastChannel.postMessage({ type: 'open', value: target });
          openWindowsTarget.push(target);
          localWindows[target] = window.open(url, target);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

I think this is works for you. I have added one line - localWindows[target].focus(); // <--------- this line

This don't works on multiple application instances

can you please explain what is multiple application instances? I am not understand

mulitple browser tab of same website
